# Salesforce API PHP: Generate Token Error SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO

Tags: php, curl, salesforce

I am referring to API >> http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php

I have to generate token to add lead into SF.

Below is my code>>
`

```
if (!isset($code) || $code == "") {
    die("Error - code parameter missing from request!");
}

$params = "code=" . $code. "&grant_type=authorization_code". "&client_id=" . CLIENT_ID. "&client_secret=" . CLIENT_SECRET. "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode(REDIRECT_URI);

$curl = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Connection: Keep-Alive'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 200 ) {
    die("Error: call to token URL $token_url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$access_token = $response['access_token'];
$instance_url = $response['instance_url'];
if (!isset($access_token) || $access_token == "") {
    die("Error - access token missing from response!");
}
if (!isset($instance_url) || $instance_url == "") {
    die("Error - instance URL missing from response!");
}
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
$_SESSION['instance_url'] = $instance_url;
`
```

Above code is working fine on my localhost, but returns below error on server>>

```
Error: call to token URL https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token failed with status 0, response , curl_error error:140740BF:SSL routines:SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO:no protocols available, curl_errno 35
```

We have installed SSL on server. Please advice about issue.

Thanks.

Comment: i am from PHP i have no idea bout salesforce, but Check this Link :https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099wwIAA

Comment: What is the version of the openssl library? Make sure OpenSSL is at least 1.0.1 to support TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.

Comment: @vladykx - I checked @ [https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check](https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check) & it says **"tls_version":"TLS 1.2"** It seems ok, is it?

Comment: You're checking it via browser, which uses different SSL library. Trying dumping the output of curl_version(). You will have array, which contains 'ssl_version' key.

Comment: @vladykx - It is ** [ssl_version] => OpenSSL/0.9.8b** do I need to upgrade this to minimum 1.0.1 ? How can I? 
`Array ( [version_number] => 466176 [age] => 3 [features] => 34493 [ssl_version_number] => 0 [version] => 7.29.0 [host] => x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu [ssl_version] => OpenSSL/0.9.8b [libz_version] => 1.2.3 [protocols] => Array ( [0] => dict [1] => file [2] => ftp [3] => ftps [4] => gopher [5] => http [6] => https [7] => imap [8] => imaps [9] => ldap [10] => ldaps [11] => pop3 [12] => pop3s [13] => rtsp [14] => scp [15] => sftp [16] => smtp [17] => smtps [18] => telnet [19] => tftp ) )`

Comment: It's hard to say for sure - depends on your system. It seems you run RHEL, so try `sudo yum update openssl`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is old OpenSSL library (0.9.8b) that doesn't support TLS 1.2. You need to install OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher to get TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 support.